# Understanding the Garbage Collector / underlying CLR of .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, clr

Could you point me to some books or websites detailing (in depth) the underlying mechanisms and interfaces used in the CLR & Garbage Collector of the .Net Framework (say 4.0 and on)?

I am ultimately trying to learn how to commandeer the garbage collector into thinking that a managed item has been marked when it talks to an unmanaged list containing said item, and feel I may need to learn a bit before being even remotely successful.

Comment: What do you mean by "marked" in this context - marked for collection, marked as pinned?

Comment: A good book would be CLR via C#, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do. If you provide more info, then possibly someone will be able to answer whatever specific questions you may have.

Answer (score 4):

One of the best articles I've read on the internals is [MSDN Magazine Issue 2005 May - JIT and Run – Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](https://arghya.xyz/assets/downloads/Objects_MSDN_May2005.pdf).

A good book to understand the internals is Jeffery Richter's [CLR Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454).

While it is stuck on the v2.0 runtime internals, the [SSCLI (e.g. Rotor)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) is still quite relevant to understand .Net 4.x internals. While there are differences between it and the production run-time, a lot of the concepts are the same.

The GC in 4.0 and 4.5 has indeed evolved though, and one of the engineers, [Maoni Stephens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/), has kept us abreast of the updates, including background concurrency and sustained low latency.

In terms of your specific need, there are really just two cases: you are using the PInvoke services, in which case you don't need to worry about the GC affecting your managed object from the native side, since PInvoke takes care of this for you, and the case where you have to explicitly pin the object on the GC heap since otherwise it could move or be collected while being used in unmanaged code. For this, you can use C# `fixed` or C++/CLI `pin_ptr` or use [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`Pro .NET Performance` from Sasha Goldshtein has an entire Chapter dedicated to the Garbage Collector. He covers the topic with very detailed and accurate information.

[Pro .NET Performance Link](http://www.apress.com/9781430244585)

As someone else has mentioned `CLR via C#` from Jeffrey Richter - the 4th (Updated for 4.5 although the GC part didn't change alot) edition recently came out which I can also recommend you.

Answer (score 0):

The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) is always a good source of information.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231

Comment: He's asking for a link to a BOOK OR DOCUMENT describing it. I have provided this information.